# How to download a list of transactions using the Google Pay API?

Tags: google-pay

Is there any way to download a list of transactions in your Google Pay account via their [API](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview)?

There seems to be very little documentation for Google Pay, and the only docs I can find just explain how to use the Web/Javascript based API to request and process a payment. There doesn't seem to be any functionality in the API for requesting historical payment records in the account. Is that feature just not supported?

Comment: No, this feature isn't available.